# Is it possible to use rackunit in DrRacket with language set to sicp, and if so, how?

Tags: racket, sicp, rackunit

I'm starting to work through SICP using DrRacket. I installed the sicp package, and declared `#lang sicp` at the top of the unit test file and then `(require rackunit "xxx.scm")`, but I get an *unbound identifier* error. Is there a mistake, or is it not possible to use rackunit with the sicp package in this way?

Comment: [you can use simply scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203498/adding-simply-scheme-language-to-drracket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `#%require`.

[`#%require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._%7E23%7E25require%29%29) is actually a primitive type in the lowest level of racket and it is slightly different than [`require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._require%29%29):

```
#lang sicp
(#%require rackunit "xxx.scm")
```

The file you want to test becomes a module so you can use it from other code by providing the identifiers you want to expose:

```
(#%provide procedure-name)
```

You can also just require a few needed forms. eg. `error` and `time` from `racket/base`:

```
(#%require (only racket/base error time))
```

A hint on finding out where they are is to search the online manuals or from Help > Racket documentation in DrRacket. Eg. here is an example of searching [`error`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=error) where you have many choices, but the racket prefixed ones are the ones you're looking for.

*NB: Not all forms are compatible across languages. Eg. R5RS has different pair implementation than `#lang racket`*

Comment: Hmm OK, the code is erroring at a different point now, *unbound identifier* error at the first reference to a function defined in the source file. Any ideas? I'm calling *check-equal?* to test the code from the source.

Comment: @RodPValley You have to use like this way: `#lang sicp` use `(#%require rackunit "test.scm")` and `(#%provide a-function-name)`

Comment: I got it now, I had not realised that I needed the `provide` combined with the `#%require`. It is now working, thanks for the suggestions everyone.